# Как ввести в react-input значение вместо пользователя

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Не получается заставить реакт считать, что пользователь ввёл в input некое значение.
Запускать собираюсь из консоли браузера.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { value: "initial msg" }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange} />
        {" "}
        {this.state.value}
      </div>
     )
  }

  onChange = ({target: {value}}) => {
    this.setState({ value })
    console.log("New value:", value)
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('main'))

var inp = document.querySelector('input');
inp.value = "test"
inp.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="//unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="//unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<main></main>
```

Comment: Мне кажется, здесь небольшое расхождение. Вы слушаете событие `onChange` , но диспатчите событие `input`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, реакт не может слушать настоящий `change`, поскольку он происходит при потере фокуса, а рект реагирует на ввод каждого символа. А ещё, этот код [работает](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40895494/4928642) в более ранней версии реакта.

Comment: меня мучает вопрос..зачем мы это делаем? нельзя ли  просто componentDidMount   применить - и записать нужное значение?

Comment: @СергейПетрашко, мне надо из консоли браузера на чужом сайте применить свой скрипт, который определённым образом заполнит поля. Так что трогать код - не вариант.

Comment: @СергейПетрашко, разобрались :)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, разобрались :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, Супер!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще не имитировать событие, а вызвать обработчик. Обработчики лежат в объекте `.__reactEventHandlers$2hkln2vgbk3`, но хэш после `$` может отличаться.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { value: "initial msg" }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange} />
        {" "}
        {this.state.value}
      </div>
     )
  }

  onChange = ({target: {value}}) => {
    this.setState({ value })
    console.log("New value:", value)
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('main'))

var inp = document.querySelector('input')
inp.value = "new value"
for (var key in inp) {
  if (key.startsWith('__reactEventHandlers$')) {
    inp[key].onChange && inp[key].onChange({ target: inp })
  }
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="//unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="//unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<main></main>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно еще вызвать `onChange` непосредственно у экземпляра компонента.

Единственная проблема - получить этот экземпляр :)

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { value: "initial msg" }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange} />
        {" "}
        {this.state.value}
      </div>
     )
  }

  onChange = ({target: {value}}) => {
    this.setState({ value })
    console.log("New value:", value)
  }
}

const main = ReactDOM.render(<App /> , document.querySelector('main'))

const inp = document.querySelector('input');
inp.value = 'new value';
main.onChange({
  target: inp
});
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="//unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="//unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<main></main>
```

Еще есть такой вариант на костылях)

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { value: "initial msg" }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange} />
        {" "}
        {this.state.value}
      </div>
     )
  }

  onChange = ({target: {value}}) => {
    this.setState({ value })
    console.log("New value:", value)
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App /> , document.querySelector('main'))

function findFiberNode(fiberNode, target) {
  if (fiberNode.stateNode == target) {
    return fiberNode;
  } else if (fiberNode.child) {
    return findFiberNode(fiberNode.child, target);
  } else if (fiberNode.sibling) {
    return findFiberNode(fiberNode.sibling, target);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

const inp = document.querySelector('input');
const main = document.querySelector('main');
const fiberNode = findFiberNode(main._reactRootContainer._internalRoot.current, inp);
inp.value = 'new value';
fiberNode.memoizedProps.onChange({
  target: inp
});
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="//unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="//unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<main></main>
```

Comment: Что за фигня вместо форматирования?

Comment: Я же писал про запуск из консоли браузера, т. е. код не менять. К тому же, предположение, что это компонент верхнего уровня значительно преувеличено.

Comment: @Qwertiy Фигню вместо форматирования делает сниппет. У меня нет настроенного jsx, что бы красиво отформатировать. Я поэтому и написал, что проблема получить экземпляр компонента. Возможно, есть способ.

Comment: Форматирование исправил (а вообще, не надо было жать "привести в порядок" и можно было его отменить Ctrl+Z в соответствующем поле).

Comment: Идея хорошая с поиском ноды. Узнал чуть больше про внутренности реакта :) Хотя алгоритм перебора настораживает.