# Как опознать framework market.kontur.ru

Tags: javascript, dom

Хочу с помощью Userscript для сервиса market.kontur.ru сделать некоторые дополнения в функциональности, но возникла проблема: меняя значение какого-либо поля ввода, это значение через несколько секунд возвращается к предыдущему значению. Думаю, связано с тем, что все введенные данные (если вручную вводить) сохраняются на сервере сразу после ввода каждого поля. Как выяснить, какую ф-ю вызвать, чтобы после изменения поля скриптом оно принялось сервером?

Какой фреймворк они используют?

Я в курсе о наличии средств отладки. У меня не получается отловить место, которое изменяет значения обратно, поэтому при поиске ответа на свой вопрос я не видел "Связанный". К моему вопросу он отношение имеет мизерное.

Comment: Почему вы решили, что там используется какой-то фреймворк?

Comment: там имена классов элементов, id (если есть) не осмысленные слова, а случайно сгенерированные длинные идентификаторы, поэтому я так предположил.

Comment: Там используется react. Поставить значения - не совсем тривиальная задача, решение которой зависит от версии react. Посмотрите вот эту тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/922888/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-react-input-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F/923633#923633